# How to arrange items inside a flexbox container even after resizing?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flexbox

I have the following pen which I was trying out for my web project.

`Source Code:` https://codepen.io/RichardRodjues/pen/oNbEaVy

Basically, the items inside the flexbox has to be draggable and resizable and should not overlap each other inside the flex container. The items in the flex container can be dragged around to switch position. However, once it is resized, the items seems to lose its position within the flex container. I have tried to look around for solutions but have not been successful. I look forward to any help that you have with your knowledge. Thank you in advance!

Screenshot of the problem faced:

[image]

Comment: https://codepen.io/rudesoul/pen/JjGpeym 

I tried my best. Do check. It works for **box1**